# Can you run at your maximum heart rate?

Tags: running, cardio, heart-rate

Is it possible to run at your maximum heart rate?

I dont think a running maximum heart rate is the same as an absolute maximum heart rate, but I have no evidence for this. [One answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/2039/8485) to a Stackexchange question of how to find your max heart rate states that you will pass out before hitting your max. McMillan's pace graph implies that there is a pace at which running faster will no longer increase your heart rate. That implies sprinting is possible at max HR.[image: McMillan Training Zone Graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my personal experience, "maximum heart rate" is a bit of a wildcard but the [Mayo Clinic describes it](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/in-depth/exercise-intensity/art-20046887?pg=2) as:

> ...the upper limit of what your cardiovascular system can handle
>   during physical activity.

I've always understood that as "*the maximum heart rate your body can safely achieve.*" It's not like you drop dead one BPM over your "max", and there's way too much variability in the human population to simply do the "220-[your age]".

Long before you get near your "max", you'll cross the [lactate/anaerobic threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactate_threshold): the point where you cease [aerobic cellular respiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_respiration#Aerobic_respiration) and switch to [anaerobic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_respiration). Even someone well trained in anaerobic threshold training can only maintain that level for a short time (minutes, typically).

There's a [2004 study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3438148/) that really gets into some of this as well if you're interested.

Specifically answering your question of: **Is it possible to run at your maximum heart rate?**

Yes. Indeed, it's probably the only way you will ever get to your "max". I personally saw my heartrate monitor blinking 199 (meaning it was higher than 199) when doing hill sprints on my road bike during my training years ago. *It hurts* to push that hard, and I would encourage you to only push into levels like that with a solid training plan and under the eye of a competent trainer.